# Lower memory usage of celery tasks?

Tags: django, celery

I'm using django, celery and rabbitmq to run 2 periodic tasks and 6 ad-hoc tasks. All of the tasks are located in (app)/tasks.py. The periodic and ad-hoc tasks are split between two seperate queues (high_priority_queue and low_priority_queue).

I have three supervisor commands setup for the beat and the two queues:

```
$ ./manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --beat
$ ./manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue
$ ./manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue
```

The tasks.py file is around 686 lines of python and is mostly doing networking and DB work. There are 15 lines of imports and around 14 Django models.Model classes in one import line being imported in.

On my ubuntu server I can see each thread is using between 41-48MB of RES memory. I feel this is a lot and I'm wondering if there is a way to bring the RES memory usage of each thread down. Is there a code organisation trick I can do? Should I import models right before their used in each task or something?

Here is an excerpt from top:

```
VIRT  RES  SHR %MEM COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                            18701 mark      20   0  253m  61m 1396 S   26  8.3   0:10.90 /home/mark/.virtualenvs/searchrank.is/bin/python /home/mark/searchrank.is/src/manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
320m  59m 1400  8.1 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
317m  59m 1360  8.0 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
303m  45m 1172  6.2 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
300m  43m 1056  5.9 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
300m  43m  348  5.9 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
305m  30m    0  4.1 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
305m  29m    0  4.0 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
306m  27m    8  3.7 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
305m  25m   16  3.5 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
304m  24m    0  3.4 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
304m  24m   12  3.4 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
305m  19m    4  2.7 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
230m  19m  164  2.6 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --beat                                                                
306m  18m    0  2.5 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=high_priority_queue                          
303m  16m    4  2.3 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --autoscale=2,1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --queues=low_priority_queue                           
299m  15m 1020  2.2 .../manage.py celeryd --concurrency=1 --verbosity=3 --loglevel=INFO --beat
```

Comment: A worker process only takes 4,5MB for me, which grows to 5MB after the first task.

Comment: But this is without Django, django preloads loads and loads of stuff bringing it up to 14MB.  With a main worker process of 20MB without django, and 32MB with django.  So for memory usage it's better to avoid using Django, but you can also use the eventlet pool (--pool=eventlet) to skip the overhead of multiple processes)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. btw, thanks for everything on https://github.com/ask I owe you a million beers.